# How to write "drag" event for objects on canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, mouseevent, drag

(i correct the mousedown thing..)

What i want to realize is to drag a ball on the canvas and then the ball will follow the mouse and change its color.

Once the mouse releases it, its color turns back to original.

i use "break" because only one ball could be dragged at one time.

Now the problem is,

1. "drag" seems weird, it seems "dragging" the first ball, but only mousemove(no mouse press) is ok right after the first ball.
2. the color doesn't change

main function below (**complete code here** http://jsfiddle.net/nyTkU/1/):

```
var mousePress = false;
var mouseEvent = function(){

$(canvas).mousedown(function(e){

    mousePress = true;

    $(canvas).mousemove(function(e){

            for(var i=0;i<figureNum;i++){

                var distX=e.pageX-balls[i].x;
                var distY=e.pageY-balls[i].y;
                var distance = Math.sqrt((distX*distX)+(distY*distY));

                if(distance<=20){
                    balls[i].x=e.pageX;
                    balls[i].y=e.pageY;
                    if(mousePress){
                       balls[i].c="#F05133";
                    }


                    break;
                }

                //else{balls[i].c="#FFED79";}

        }
    });
});


$(canvas).mouseup(function(e){

    mousePress=false;

    //for(var i=0;i<figureNum;i++){

    //  balls[i].c="#FFED79";

    //}
})

setTimeout(animate,speedMouse);
   }
```

Many many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have two mouseDown events...maybe the second one should be mouseUp?

I'm still a little confused on your desired functionality. Do you want the ball to move only if mouseDown=true or a ball should move if it is clicked once? Because you should be using click() handler in the second case.

Your mouseMove seems odd as well...are you trying to get any ball within a certain distance D to bind to the mouse coordinates? That will create some odd behavior.

Best way to do this would be:

1) On mouseDown, detect if a ball has been selected and save that ID. (set mousePressed=true)

2) On mouseMove, if mousePressed=true && ball is selected, bind that ball to the mouse coordinates. Do not update() this ball with any velocity.

3) On mouseUp, set mousePressed=false and clear any selected Ball

Comment: Thank you so much, it helps a lot. The result is good: http://jsfiddle.net/nyTkU/5/  except one out of three or four drags, a forbidden sign would appear and prevent user from dragging object within the canvas. that's the only odd thing.

Comment: Maybe try adding `$(canvas).drag(function(){return false;});` to suppress the "forbidden sign". Also look into the `.dragstart`, `.dragend`, and `.dblclick` events (see http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp for a list of all DOM events)